# Separating BusinessModel from ViewModel in Prism,MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I was going through WPF Prism examples. In Brian repo found this easy example on simple MVVM WPF app: 
https://github.com/brianlagunas/InfragisticsWebinarSimpleMVVMPrism/tree/master/PrismDemo

Now I want to put firstName,lastName and lastUpdated properties in separate class, its  "Business Model" called Person. I wrote something like this and I wonder, if it is correct.

In ViewAViewModel i set up property person using prism snippet:

```
private Person person;
public Person Person
{
    get { return person; }
    set { SetProperty(ref person, value); }
}
```

And my Person class looks like this:

```
public class Person:BindableBase
    {

        private string firstName = "Karol";
        public string FirstName 
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref firstName, value);
            }
        }
}
```

Now, is it a correct way to do this. I read somewhere, that in person class i should rather use standard OnPropertyChanged() method. What do you think?

EDIT:

I remembered what I was wondering about. I have watched Brian Langunas webinar about Prism and he said that Person prop in ViewModel should be done like this:

```
private Person _person;
public Person Person
{
    get { return _person; }
    set
    {
        if (_person != null)
            _person.PropertyChanged -= Person.PropetryChanged;
        SetProperty(ref _person, value);
        if (_person != null) 
            _person.PropertyChanged -= Person.PropetryChanged;
    }
}
```

He is saying, that it has sth to do with memory management. The property Person can be set multipe times within ViewMode llifetime,you have to first check if you have a previous instance and unsubscribe it. If you dont, then you can have memory leaks. But this was long time ago ( 2015 ), maybe it is fixed somehow. Here is the link (1:04:20): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY Can you refer to that? Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach except maybe for the fact that is has a dependency upon `Prism` and the `BindableBase` class.

If `Person` is part of a "larger" domain and may also be used in your service and/or business layer(s), you probably not want this.

Then you'd better make it a plain old CLR (POCO) object that has no dependencies on any third-party UI frameworks. It may of course still implement the built-in `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface though.